# No serializer found for class org.mule.module.jersey.MuleResponseWriter$1 while using APIKit

Tags: mule, mule-studio

When I use APIKit router with a Rest(jersey) component, I am getting a exception( as below), this exception does not occur when I use a flow-ref instead of the API Router ( Inserted flow snippet below). Any clues ?

Message               : No serializer found for class org.mule.module.jersey.MuleResponseWriter$1 and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException)

### Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2

Exception stack is:
1. No serializer found for class org.mule.module.jersey.MuleResponseWriter$1 and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException)
  org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer:52 (null)
2. No serializer found for class org.mule.module.jersey.MuleResponseWriter$1 and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException) (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)
  org.mule.module.json.transformers.ObjectToJson:103

```
<flow name="main" doc:name="main">
    <http:inbound-endpoint  doc:name="HTTP" exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="9081"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
         <apikit:router config-ref="apiConfig" doc:name="APIkit Router"/>
    <exception-strategy ref="apiKitGlobalExceptionMapping" doc:name="Reference Exception Strategy"/>
</flow>
<flow name="wine-cellar-muleFlow1" doc:name="wine-cellar-muleFlow1">
    <jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
        <component class="WineResource"/>
    </jersey:resources>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the class MuleResponseWriter has some fields which do not have public getters or setters.